# スクリプトエディタに登録されているプログラムの自動のアラームメールが　突然届かなくなりました

Tags: google-apps-script

お世話になっております。
前任が作成し、私はまったくの素人で全く分からないまま困っております。
ご存知の方がありましたら以下についてご教示をお願いいたします。

＜利用内容＞
スプレッドシートで有期雇用者の契約満了日などを管理。それに対し、契約更新の可否の判断を忘れないよう、契約満了日の45日前に「契約を確認してください」というメールが自動的に届くようにしていた。

＜状況＞
自動で送信されるメールの送信元の送信履歴には、最後に送信された7月18日までの履歴はあるが、それ以降は送信されておらず、こちらでは受信もしていない。
今回のトラブルまでは、スクリプトエディタの存在すら知らず、何も情報は触っていない。

解決には情報が不足しているかもしれないのですが何を調べて良いのかもわからずです。
ご教示ただける方、どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: > `最後に送信された7月18日までの履歴はある` このタイミングで前任者のG Suiteアカウントを削除したりしましたか？

Comment: はい、退職者のため5月29日に削除済みでした。